# Shell script - "Wait" does not wait for all processes to complete

Tags: bash, shell, docker, parallel-processing, wait

In a shell script I am building some docker images(in background), once done I am running them(in background) and then I have to wait for all of them to complete. The code looks like this:

```
for tag in "${tags[@]}"
do
    docker build -f dockerFilePath -t $tag . &
done

wait

for tag in "${tags[@]}"
do 
    docker run $tag arg1 arg2 | tee logoutput &
done

wait
```

The problem is that not all the docker run commands in the second wait section are able to complete. And the docker run commands take different times to complete, and any one of them is always incomplete (among a total of 4).

Also, I read that wait only works for the direct children of the process calling wait, in this case I think all the docker build and docker run commands are the direct children of the script process. Or is that wrong to assume?

Comment: @Inian Yes, that is fine, since the build is really fast as it is done from cache so they are completed almost instantaneously.

Comment: For some debugging, inserting `jobs` before and after the `wait` might be useful.... It should show nothing after the `wait`... a `ps` (with some parameters, probably `-f`) might also be useful to verify that the jobs are actually still running... (When running from the command line, the `b` `set` option might make you think that other things are going on than you think...)

Comment: Consider using **GNU Parallel**, your script becomes 2 lines and much more controllable, loggable, restartable. `parallel --dry-run docker build -f dockerFilePath -t $tag . ::: "${tags[@]}"`